# embedded c++ : dynamic typing without dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, embedded, dynamic-typing, static-allocation

**Here's my issue, simplified:**

- I have a code in C/C++, C for services, C++ for handling.
- I have an interface in C that returns a structure RawData that contains information which is cyclically updated.

```
    enum AnimalType_t
    {
                DOG                         = 0,
                GREY_HOUND                  = 1,
                IMMORTAL_JELLYFISH          = 2,
    };
    struct RawData_t
    {
        int             age;
        AnimalType_t    typeOfAnimal;
    };

    RawData_t GetMyCurrentRawData();//returns the current raw data
    bool      IsDataReady(); //returns true if data is ready, false otherwise
```

- I have a virtual mother class "Animal"

```
    class Animal
    {
    public:
        virtual Animal();
        virtual ~Animal();
        int GetType() { return rawAttributes.typeOfAnimal; };   //the only implementation for all children
        virtual int GetAge() { return rawAttributes.age; };     //to be implemented in the child class
        virtual void UpdateAge() { rawAttributes.age++; };  //to be implemented in the child class
        virtual int GetNumberOfLegs() = 0;                      //to be implemented in the child class
    private:
        RawData_t rawAttributes;
    }
```

- I have a known list of animals which inherit from the mother class.

```
    class Dog : public Animal
    {
    public:
        Dog(RawData rawData):Animal(rawData){};
        int GetNumberOfLegs() {return 4;};                  
    };

    class GreyHound : public Dog
    {
    public:
        GreyHound(RawData rawData):Dog(rawData){};
    };

    class ImmortalJellyFish : public Animal
    {
    public:
        ImmortalJellyFish(RawData rawData):Animal(rawData){};
        int GetNumberOfLegs() {return 0;};      
        void UpdateAge() { return;} override;
    };
```

- I have a class "Building" in which there is one, only one, animal but I don't know its type when I instantiate the building.

```
    class Building
    {
    public:
        Building(){};
        //sorry for the long line, but you get the idea...
        int Display(void){if(IsDataReady()) DisplayOnScreen("This animal ( "+ animal_m.GetType()+") has " + animal_m.GetNumberOfLegs() + "legs and is " + animal_m.GetAge() + " years old\n";};
        int Live(void){currentDiagCode_m.UpdateAge();};

    private:
        auto                        animal_m; //?? not working
    };

    static Building paddock;
    static Building farm;

    void Buildings_Step(void)
    {
        paddock.Live();
        paddock.Display();
        farm.Live();
        farm.Display();
    }
```

**Here's where i'm struggling:**

- allocate memory for an animal in a Building without knowing its type during building instantiation,
- type and attributes of the animal might change cyclically
  In other words: is dynamic typing with static allocation possible?
  Then, how can I call these instances so the right method is called?

**Here're my constraints:**

- embedded system
- no dynamic memory allocation

**I though about :**

- factory design pattern with unique_ptr which works great!!!... but, on the heap :(
- Object Pool?
- dynamic typing: but non possible without dynamic allocation, is it?

***Is there any design/model that could fulfill my needs?***

Thank you!

Comment: You should focus on the actual application and what it should do. Then come up with a design based on that, rather than coming up with "a meta design that suits your design". Embedded systems are rarely ever dynamic, nor do we want them to be, because we always have limited resources and we want them to behave deterministically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, memory allocation and object existence are two separate concepts, even though in most situations you'll handle both together. In your case, though, you may wish to explicitly separate the two:

1. Create enough memory for any object:

   ```
   char buf[N];    // N >= sizeof(T) for all T in your hierarchy
   ```
2. To create an animal:

   ```
   new (buf) GreyHound(args);
   ```
3. To destroy an existing animal (and make room for another):

   ```
   reinterpret_cast<Animal*>(buf)->~Animal();
   ```

That is, you obtain storage as part of your container object, but you manage the Animal object lifetime dynamically with placement-new and explicit destruction.

There's a bit more to this: your memory also needs to be aligned correctly for all types that you construct in it. You can use some library helper traits like `std::aligned_storage` or `std::aligned_union` to simplify the computation, though you'll probably still need to do a bit of work to compute both the size and the alignment.

---

As a completely separate alternative, you could forego the polymorphic class hierarchy and use a `std::variant` instead. This is conceptually similar, but a somewhat different approach implementation-wise. The reason that this is conceptually similar is because you have a bounded set of types, so you don't really need polymorphism to handle *arbitrary, unknown* derived types at runtime.